# macOS 12.1: Preview window persists after deciding what to do with screenshot

Tags: macos, apple-silicon, monterey

16" M1 Max/64GB/4TB. Updated from 12.0.1 to 12.1 a couple of days ago. I now have a problem with the Screenshot app; usually, when you take a screenshot, and decide what you want to do with it, the Preview window disappears - not anymore, now it's persisting, and the only way to get shot of it is by logging out properly or rebooting. I use it extensively, so this is rather more than a minor inconvenience.

- I can't kill it via force quit, as it doesn't appear in the force quit box,
- Doing jiggery-pokery in safe mode hasn't proved fruitful.
- Doesn't matter if I activate it via the app or CTR-CMD-4/5, the result is the same,

Any ideas on how to resolve this?  This is the window I mean

[image]

Comment: If you press Shift-Cmd-5 and check in the options, is the preview enabled there?

Comment: Also, at least a screenshot (sic!) of the window in question would be helpful :-)

Comment: The window is the standard Preview window which appears in the bottom right after you've taken a screenshot. I have a video of what happens, but I'm not sure I'm allowed to post YouTube links here - am I? When you bring it up to select what you want to do with the shot from the square/arrow button menu, it doesn't disappear after you've selected an option (usually it's Photos). Does that make sense?